# How does authentication work when using Invoke-Command?

Tags: powershell

I'm looking for a good reference to understand what actually behinds the scene of Invoke-Command. Does this retrieve current logged user context to run command remotely? So saying I'm a domain admin who has administrative rights on target joined computers so what I'd need to do just like

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName mypc -FilePath "C:\Script\stuff.ps"
```

> Connecting to remote serve mypc failed with the following error
>   message : WinRM cannot complete the operation. Verify that the
>   specified computer name is valid, that the computer is accessible over
>   the network, and that a  firewall exception for the WinRM service is
>   enabled and allows access from this computer. By default, the WinRM
>   firewall exception for public profiles limits access to remote
>   computers within the same local subnet.

If I try with the following code snippet I'm able to access to the pc

```
$so = New-PsSessionOption –SkipCACheck -SkipCNCheck
Enter-PSSession -ComputerName mypc -Credential contoso\admin -UseSSL -SessionOption $so -Authentication Kerberos
```

The error output from `Invoke-Command` seems to indicate that it uses WinRm but I don't know the main difference between the first compared with the second one.

Comment: All PowerShell Remoting uses WinRM - it is built on top of that service.  Your second attempt isn't using a different mechanism, only different options for connecting (essentially skipping some security checks).  Seems like a configuration issue as the first command should work if you are a local admin on the target, as you say.  Check out the [Remote Troubleshooting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_remote_troubleshooting?view=powershell-6) help for some advice.

Comment: where you running the script "as administrator"? i have found that i need to add `#requires -RunAsAdministrator` to the top of scripts that use `Invoke-Command` against a remote system.

Comment: @boxdog both commands are run under the same account with my param `-Credential`. 

@Lee_Dailey yes the PowerShell was open to run as administrator. That is why I'm kinda surprised and really want to know the main difference since both are going under WinRm.